Origin of action of symmetric groups in Lurie's definition of operad in Higher Algebra
I'm somewhat confused about a passage in Lurie's "Higher Algebra." Let me first give the relevant definitions.

Definition ([HA, Definition 2.1.1.1]). A colored operad $\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}\cO$ consists of the following data:

A collection $\{X, Y, Z, \ldots\}$ which we will refer to as the collection of objects or colors of $\cO$.   We will indicate that
$X$ is an object of $\cO$ by writing $X \in \cO$.
For every finite set $I$, every $I$-indexed collection of objects $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $\cO$, and every object $Y \in \cO$, a set $\newcommand{\Mul}{\operatorname{Mul}}\Mul_{\cO}(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y)$, which we call the set of morphisms from $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ to $Y$.
For every map of finite sets $I \to J$ having fibers $\{I_j\}_{j \in J}$, every finite collection of objects $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$, every finite collection of objects $\{Y_j\}_{j \in J}$, and every object $Z \in \cO$, a composition map             \begin{equation*}
     \prod_{j \in J} \Mul_{\cO}(\{X_i\}_{i \in I_j}, Y_j) \times \Mul_{\cO}(\{Y_j\}_{j \in J}, Z) \to \Mul_{\cO}(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Z)
 \end{equation*}
A collection of morphisms $\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}\{\id_X \in \Mul_{\cO}(\{X\}, X)\}_{X \in \cO}$ which are both left and right
units for the composition on $\cO$ in the following sense: For every
finite collection of objects $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ and every object $Y \in \cO$, the compositions
\begin{align*}
     \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y) &\simeq \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y) \times \{\id_Y\} \\
               &\subseteq \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y) \times \Mul_\cO(\{Y\}, Y) \\
               &\to \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y)    \end{align*}             and             \begin{align*}
     \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y) &\simeq \prod_{i \in I} \{\id_{X_i}\} \times \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y) \\
               &\subseteq \prod_{i \in I} \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}, X_i) \times \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y) \\
               &\to \Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y)    \end{align*}
both coincide with the identity map from $\Mul_\cO(\{X_i\}_{i \in I}, Y)$ to itself.
Composition is associative in the following sense: For every sequence of maps $I \to J \to K$ of finite sets together with
collections of objects $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$, $\{X_j\}_{j \in J}$,
$\{Y_k\}_{k \in K}$, and every object $Z \in \cO$, the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$ \begin{CD}
     \prod_{j \in J} \Mul_\cO(\{W_i\}_{i \in I_j}, X_j) \times \prod_{k \in K} \Mul_\cO(\{X_j\}_{j \in J_k}, Y_k) \times \Mul_\cO(\{Y_k\}_{k
 \in k}, Z) @>>> \prod_{k \in K} \Mul_\cO(\{W_i\}_{i \in I_k}, Y_k)
 \times \Mul_\cO(\{Y_k\}_{k \in K}, Z) \\
     @VVV @VVV \\
     \prod_{j \in J} \Mul_\cO(\{W_i\}_{i \in I_j}, X_j) \times \Mul_\cO(\{X_j\}_{j \in J}, Z) @>>> \Mul_\cO(\{W_i\}_{i \in I}, Z) 
 \end{CD}
is commutative.



Definition ([HA, Example 2.1.1.6]). An operad is a colored operad $\cO$ having only a single color $\mathbf{1}$. For every
nonnegative integer $n$ we let $\cO_n = \Mul(\{\mathbf{1}\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}, \mathbf{1})$. We sometimes refer to $\cO_n$ as the set of
$n$-ary operations of $\cO$. The structure of $\cO$ as a colored
operad is determined by the sets $\{\cO_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ together with
the actions of the symmetric groups $\Sigma_n$ on $\cO_n$ and the
"substitution maps"
$$
     \cO_m \times \prod_{1 \leq i \leq m} \cO_{n_i} \to \cO_{n_1 + \cdots + n_m} 
 $$

(bold emphasis mine)
I'm struggling to see where this $\Sigma_n$-action is supposed to come from. Certainly there's no talk of any such action in the definition of colored operad.

I'm aware that "usual" definitions of (symmetric) operad include a $\Sigma_n$-action on $\cO_n$ as part of the data. I've also seen that the nlab definition of colored operad explicitly requires such an action, as opposed to Lurie's definition above.
I'm therefore left to wonder whether there's maybe an error of omission here. If that's not the case, I'd like to ask for an explanation of what the intended $\Sigma_n$-action in the highlighted sentence in the second definition is and how it serves to determine the structure of $\cO$ as a colored operad.

I'd look at datum 3 in the definition of a colored operad, specifically in the case when $I=J$ and when the map $I \to J$ is a permutation $\sigma$. In this case, picking the identity morphisms $\operatorname{id} \in \operatorname{Mul}{\mathcal{O}}\left(\left{X{\sigma^{-1}\left(j\right)}\right}, Y_j\right)$ in the first argument of the map $\prod_{j \in J} \Mul_{\cO}({X_i}{i \in I_j}, Y_j) \times \Mul{\cO}({Y_j}{j \in J}, Z) \to \Mul{\cO}({X_i}{i \in I}, Z)$, we obtain a map $\Mul{\cO}({Y_j}{j \in J}, Z) \to \Mul{\cO}({X_i}_{i \in I}, Z)$ that can be viewed as ...

... the action of $\sigma$ on $\mathcal{O}_n$.
